# Running MS-Word macro with python

Tags: python, win32com

I'm trying to run a macro I usually run manually thorugh word using python.
The macro baiscly cleans the document - (removes extra spaces, empty lines, etc)
what i've tried to do so far is

```
import win32com.client
import os, os.path

if os.path.exists("example_report.docx"):
    dcmnt=win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
    dcmnt.Documents.Open(os.path.abspath("example_report.docx"))
    dcmnt.Application.Run("example_report.docx!NewMacros.Clean_Report")
    dcmnt.Application.Save() 
    dcmnt.Application.Quit()
    del dcmnt
```

Right now I get an exception: pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352573), None) - which doest tell me a lot.

The Exception occures at the Application.Run line.

So far I didn't find any documentation for this topic, it would be great if someone can provide pointer to debug it and understand the error / or post a better code.

This code is a part of bigger script which automizes a proccess in my job, so replaceing it with something other than python should be problematic.

Comment: Also, I'd be surprised if you had managed to save a `docx` file containing a macro. Macro-enabled files have the `docm` extension.

Answer (score 0):

When specifying the macro name fully, you have to leave out the file extension. If the file is `example_report.docm` (NB `docx` files cannot contain macros), the module is `NewMacros` and the sub-routine is `Clean_Report`, then the fully-qualified macro name is:

`example_report!NewMacros.Clean_Report`

*You should not include the extension*. However, you only need to fully qualify the macro name if you have other macros with the same name in open documents, otherwise `Clean_Report` will likely work too (as macros are at global scope in VBA).

The Python code would be better reworked as

```
import win32com.client as wc
import os, os.path

filename = 'example_report.docm'

if os.path.exists(filename):
    wdApp = wc.Dispatch('Word.Application')
    doc = wdApp.Documents.Open(filename)
    wdApp.Run('Clean_Report')
    doc.Save()
    wdApp.Quit()
```

As an aside, the exception is indeed unhelpful. Curiously this seems to be because you included the extension in the macro parameter string. Had you called `example_report!MissingMacro` (ie a macro that didn't exist), then the exception would have been filled in with:

```
(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Word', "Can't run the specified macro", 'wdmain11.chm', 37401, -2147352573), None)
```

and would have been a lot more relevant. Odd that Word is not filling in the details in this specific instance.